# Dynamically Deleting Widgets Stored in a List is causing index error

Tags: python, tkinter

After reading some different posts here, I still cannot resolve this issue.  I'm trying to dynamically add and remove widgets from a frame using buttons.

The add button will add an entry/button/label.  The button that is added to that row should delete said row.  I am not getting the expected behavior.

What is happening is that it doesn't seem like the button command is updated properly and/or maybe I have made some other mistake in the logic.
A short reproducible example is here.  Press the add button three times, then delete the top row 3 times.  The last one will cause an index error.

There are many ways to reproduce said error (add more than 2, add several, then delete them and you can watch the index update properly in most cases.  I cannot understand the times when it doesn't, but if you add up to 4 or more and delete the top item, you can see that the index called when I hit delete on the row the second time is actually 4!?

I am pretty sure this should get fixed on the original loop when I update the command for the button?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        
        self.addButton = ttk.Button(self,command=self.add,text='Add')
        self.addButton.pack()
        
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack()
        
        self.inputs  = []
        self.buttons = []
        self.labels  = []
        
    def add(self):
        self.addButton['state'] = 'disabled'
        c = len(self.inputs)
        
        self.inputs.append(ttk.Entry(self.frame))
        self.buttons.append(ttk.Button(self.frame,text='x',command=lambda: self.remove(c)))
        self.labels.append(ttk.Label(self.frame,text=str(c)))
        
        self.inputs[c].grid(row=c,column=0)
        self.buttons[c].grid(row=c,column=1)
        self.labels[c].grid(row=c,column=2)
        
        self.addButton['state'] = 'enabled'
        return
    
    def remove(self,i):
        self.buttons[i]['state'] = 'disabled'
        print(i,self.labels[i]['text'])
        
        ## Move all buttons and lower up one
        for x in range(i+1,len(self.buttons)):
            self.buttons[x].configure(command=lambda: self.remove(x-1))
            self.buttons[x].grid(row=x-1,column=1)
            self.inputs[x].grid(row=x-1,column=0)
            self.labels[x].grid(row=x-1,column=2)
            self.labels[x].configure(text=str(x-1))
    
        ## Delete widgets
        self.buttons[i].destroy()
        self.inputs[i].destroy()
        self.labels[i].destroy()
        
        ## Remove from list
        del self.buttons[i]
        del self.inputs[i]
        del self.labels[i]
        
        return
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

EDIT:
Solution in comments.
Changed
`self.buttons[x].configure(command=lambda: self.remove(x-1))`
to
`self.buttons[x].configure(command=lambda x=x: self.remove(x-1))`

Comment: Change the line `self.buttons[x].configure(command=lambda: self.remove(x-1))` to `self.buttons[x].configure(command=lambda x=x: self.remove(x-1))` inside `remove()`.

Comment: I cannot give you enough upvotes for this comment.   Toyota's fix isn't correct as the value i being sent in is correct.  This solution solves the exact case solution I described above but leads to other arbitrary behavior.  The solution is here in the comment likely 'x' was not being passed in from lambda, but instead referencing the enclosing namespace x.